# Simple redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I know this is a simple and quick thing, but site is going live within hours and I dont have any experience on htaccess so Im hoping someone could give some quick help with this.

So what I want is that I have html files root folder. Files are index.html, german.html, swedish.html, spanish.html, danish.html. Now I would like to have the URL so that german site would be in www.domain.com/de swedish www.domain.com/sv english/default in www.domain.com/en and so on. This should be possible to do with htaccess right?

Or is there better way to do it?

Thanks alot!

Comment: This is certainly possible and the best way is indeed via htaccess. You could also do it via index.php redirect, but that is a tad bit slower than when redirecting via htaccess

Comment: How are you planning to direct users to each site - a GeoIP database on the server or a language selection on the main page that gets stored in client-side cookie?

Comment: People comes from newsletter to their own languaged versions. Its just a campaign site.

Answer (score 6):

Create a .htacess fil with the following contents:

```
Redirect permanent /german.html http://yourdomain.com/de
Redirect permanent /swedish.html http://yourdomain.com/sv
....
```

I hope this is what you ment and that it helps :)

Comment: This seems what I need. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: That's even simpler than a re-write rule. Be careful though, some browsers will cache this, and cause local problems if you have a typo in the redirect.